# Pandas remove equivalent rows from dataframe where xy = yx

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner with pandas and I'm having a little problem.

I would like to remove equivalent entries in a pandas dataframe which uses repeated columns where the column _x and column _y are repeating data by changing it's order.

For example, i have the following code that merges a data frame with itself:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ["mary","algebra"],
    ["mary","calculus"],
    ["john","algebra"],
    ["robert","calculus"]
    ],
    columns=["name","class"])

df = pd.merge(df,df,on="class").query("name_x != name_y")

print(df)
```

And the output is this:

```
   name_x     class  name_y
1    mary   algebra    john
2    john   algebra    mary
5    mary  calculus  robert
6  robert  calculus    mary
```

The problem is that some information is repeated, for example, line 1 and line 2 are equivalent because the ordering of the variable _x and _y doesn't matter for my problem, i would like if there's a way to remove the equivalent rows and turn the previous output into this one:

```
   name_x     class  name_y
1    mary   algebra    john
2    mary  calculus  robert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `lambda`:

```py
df = pd.merge(df,df,on="class").query("name_x != name_y")
df["pair"] = df[["name_x", "name_y"]].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='pair').drop(columns='pair')

print(df)
```

---

```
  name_x     class  name_y
1   mary   algebra    john
5   mary  calculus  robert
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
#is the pair of names duplicated ?
m = df.filter(like="name").apply(sorted, axis=1).duplicated()

df = df.loc[m]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   name_x     class name_y
2    john   algebra   mary
6  robert  calculus   mary
```

Comment: It worked for me, i just needed to change one thing because i was having the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

So i changed the first line to `m = df.filter(like="name").apply(sorted, axis=1).astype(str).duplicated()`

Thanks!